# Definition of a dense set in a subspace or why are the irrationals a separable topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is said to be separable, if it contains a countable dense subset. My reading material's treatment of a dense set has been (by a slight caricaturing) *A subset $A \subset X$ of a topological space is said to be dense if $\overline{A} = X$. Moving on...*. Therefore, I've been under the impression that for a set $B \subset A \subset X$ to be dense in $A$ we'd need to have that $\overline{B} = A$. But if I'm not mistaken, the proof that: [Irrational Number Space is Separable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Irrational_Number_Space_is_Separable) contradicts this line of thought. Specifically, as rationals and irrationals are dense in real numbers, shouldn't the closure of any subset of irrationals also contain rational numbers?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Which topology are we using here? If the neighborhoods are defined to be open intervals, then surely $(\sqrt{2} - 0.1, \sqrt{2} + 0.1)$ contains rational numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B\subset A\subset X$, $B$ is dense in $A$ if and only if the closure if $B$ *in* $A$ is $A$. And this is equivalent to asserting that $\overline B\supset A$.

In particular, the set $S=\Bbb Q+\sqrt2$ is dense in the irrationals since $\overline S=\Bbb R$, and therefore $\overline S\supset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: But now, why does $\overline{S} \subset (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$, as we need to have $\overline{S} = (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Did you read my answer? No, you *don't* need to have $\overline S=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. We need to have $\overline S\supset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I did read your answer. What I've understood is that $B \subset A$ is dense in $A \Longleftrightarrow$ $A \subset \overline{B} \land \overline{B}\subset A$. And I'm confused why now, with the $S$ you've proposed, we would have $\overline{S} \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The assertion $\overline S\subset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is false, and therefore I cannot explain why it is true. Why do you think that it is true? *Nowhere* in my answer I wrote that $\overline B\subset A$.

Comment: I see, so should the correct assertion be that $B \subset A \subset X$, $B$ dense in $A \Longleftrightarrow$ $\overline{B}\cap A = A$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I see, this explains everything and your answer makes now perfect sense!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Remember that closure is a relative property. That is: the same set can have different closures when viewed as a subset of different spaces. In $\mathbb{R}$, the closure of $\mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, and in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$  , the closure of $\mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$ is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$  .